# Don't Starve armour stats

Tags: dont-starve

What are the damage reduction and durability of armours in Don't Starve? Insulation values and even sanity modifiers would be a bonus as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Source](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Armor)

```
╔═══════════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║Armor Name         ║Damage Absorption║Durability  ║Other effects                                                                                      ║
╠═══════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║Grass Armor........║60%..............║........225 ║                                                                                                   ║
║Log Armor..........║80%..............║........450 ║                                                                                                   ║
║Night Armor........║95%..............║........750 ║Drains sanity by 10/min, decreases sanity by 10% of damage taken                                        ║
║Marble Suit........║95%..............║.......1050 ║Slows player by 30%                                                                                ║
║Snurtle Shell Armor║60%..............║.......1050 ║100% damage reduction when hiding                                                                                                 ║
║Thulecite Suit.....║90%..............║.......1800 ║Raises sanity by 3.3/min                                                                           ║
║Scalemail..........║70%..............║.......1800 ║Fire damage immunity, Ignites attackers, Raises sanity by 3.3/min                                     ║
║Seashell Suit......║75%..............║........750 ║Protects from poison through contact                                                               ║
║Limestone Suit.....║70%..............║........825 ║Slows player by 25%                                                                                ║
║Obsidian Armor.....║70%..............║...... 1350 ║Fire damage immunity, Ignites attackers, Raises sanity by 3.3/min                                     ║
║Football Helmet....║80%..............║........450 ║Grants 20% water resistance                                                                        ║
║Beekeeper Hat......║80%..............║........750 ║Damage absorption applies to damage taken from Bees and Killer Bees only                                                 ║
║Shelmet............║90%..............║........750 ║                                                                                                   ║
║Thulecite Crown....║90%..............║.......1200 ║Chance to activate a forcefield that blocks all damage and stuns, 5% of damage received is instead taken from sanity║
║Battle Helm........║80%..............║........750 ║Grants 20% water resistance                                                                        ║
╚═══════════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Added helmets..

Comment: What about insulation and effects on sanity? Also is it "armor reduction" or "damage reduction"? Edit: Nevermind, just saw when the answer and the question edit were posted.

Comment: Whoa, just saw the update, amazing work!